# Using material ui4 which datepicker should use for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, redux-toolkit

I'm new in ReactJS. I have start working with the ReactJS using material ui 4 and ReactJS 17.2.
I'm not able to take decesion which material date picker we need use.in my requirement I'm using input textbox with type date. But it is not working properly.

My requirement is user can select date from clicking on datepicker and select date from Calendar. Or user can type date from input.

User can input any date format it should be convert in required date format like

dd-mmm-yyyy, 24-Mar-2023

Can anyone suggest me which datepicker should I use using material ui 4?

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, we just updated our pickers today when updating to MUIv5 so I'm fresh off of looking at what we were using for MUIv4...

**(Be aware that this is a deprecated package and is no longer in active development)**

We used @material-ui/pickers [(docs)](https://v4.mui.com/components/pickers/) [(npm repo)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/pickers).  This was the preferred library for the MUI team when on v4 and they have rolled the updated version of it into the MUIv5 library.  The documentation website was taken down earlier this year, but you can access a snapshot of it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230107144512/https://material-ui-pickers.dev/).

---

In response to your comment.  Your code below should work if you set the property `format="DD-MMM-YYYY`.  It works for me in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/muiv4-keyboard-date-picker-example-c2pn6s?file=/src/App.js).  Just be sure to use the 1.3.13 version of `@date-io/[adapter]` -
I used dayjs in the example; later versions are not compatible.

If you have a choice, I would suggest you go with MUIv5 to get newer features with their `@mui/x-date-pickers` package, but if you're stuck with v4, then this should work.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers'
import DayJsUtils from '@date-io/dayjs'

export default function KeyboardDatePickerExample() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState()

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DayJsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        autoOk={true}
        value={selectedDate}
        format="DD-MMM-YYYY"
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedDate(e)}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there Any datepicker with material ui4 for ReactJS, that will make same behaviour like angular material ui datepicker https://material.angular.io/  when User can typing Any date format from date field it is automatically convert date in required date format. 
For example when user typing dd-mm-yyyy it is automatically convert in dd/mm/yyyy or user typing dd-mmm-yyyy it is automatically convert to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: This one will convert

Comment: I'm using material ui4 datepicker below libraries. `<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}> <KeyboardDatePicker autoOk={true} value={selectedDate} format="DD/MMM/YYYY" onChange={handleDateChange} /> </MuiPickersUtilsProvider> `But it is not automatically convert date format.  Is there Any dateadapter can convert auto date format using material ui 4 in ReactJS

Comment: As I have checked your example and code, but I'm not able to type date from keyboard, my code is also working fine with when I select date from datepicker calendar. But problem is that when we type date from keyboard in date field then other date format should convert in required date formate same as like angular example

Answer (score 0):

`MUI` team have been working on some complex features such as Grid and Pickers (date and time) under `mui-x`.

Quoting from the docs:

> We're officially decoupling MUI X's versioning from MUI Core (including @mui/material: Material UI). We understand that this may cause confusion, so we'd like to explain the main reasons why we're moving in this direction.

You can read the whole blog about the features and the reason that this was done [here](https://mui.com/blog/mui-x-v6/#decoupling-versions-from-mui-core).

`mui-x` should work fine with `v4`, nevertheless, I recommend upgrading your `MUI` version to 5 as soon as possible, since it includes a lot of cool features and has an awesome DX.

Comment: My requirement is need to use only material ui 4.

Comment: You can use `@mui/x-date-pickers`. It doesn't depend on `@mui/core`. It does depend on `@mui/material` though, So maybe not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Can you please give me exact example which I need to use for datepicker using material ui 4. And it should be automatically convert other date format to required date format in ReactJS

Comment: Check out this [doc](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers). I have used it with `material-ui v4`, but you have to add `@mui/core` as stated there. They don't have conflict but your bundle size will grow. Hope you find what you look for.

Comment: I'm using material ui4 datepicker below libraries. `<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}> <KeyboardDatePicker autoOk={true} value={selectedDate} format="DD/MMM/YYYY" onChange={handleDateChange} /> </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>` But it is not automatically convert date format same as like angular material ui using <MuiPickersUtilsProvider>. Kayboarddatepiccker. . How should I need to use so that it will automatically date format. Is there any provider do I need to use for automatically convert date format

Comment: I'm using material ui4 datepicker below libraries. `<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}> <KeyboardDatePicker autoOk={true} value={selectedDate} format="DD/MMM/YYYY" onChange={handleDateChange} /> </MuiPickersUtilsProvider> `But it is not automatically convert date format.  Is there Any dateadapter can convert auto date format using material ui 4 in ReactJS